# Angular2. Load non-root module for root url

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Here's the Anugular's plunker about routing:
https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/router/ts/plnkr.html

They create a few modules and load one of them (heroes) as a default. The approach they take is they simply redirect you to `site:/heroes` whenever you type just `site:/`. So every time you come to the site you mandatory end up at `site:/heroes`.

I don't like that. How can still have my url as just `site:/` but load a component from one of my modules (or heroes in that case)? Don't want to reference this component in my app module or routing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an empty path on parent and children, then `SomeComponent` gets loaded and the URL still has an empty path:

```
{ path: '', children: [
  {  path: '', component: SomeComponent }
]}
```

Here's the working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/FpO7pw1GgfARIAltlvb3?p=preview

Changes were made to app.routing.ts

```
/*{
  path: '',
  redirectTo: '/heroes',
  pathMatch: 'full'
},*/
```

and `heroes` was also removed from the path in heroes.routing.ts

Comment: Yes, but in this case you need to reference the "SomeComponent" and the idea of modules is that you only reference a module from outside, not a component within it. I'm now playing with loadChildren: 'app/crisis-center/crisis-center.module#CrisisCenterModule' trying to make it load heroes list, but no success yet.

Comment: I just tried to communicate the idea of routes and child routes with empty paths. You can use `loadChildren` and add child routes with empty paths this way as well.

Comment: Well, probably I'm playing with wrong thing here. The module#module relates to lazy loading and that's a different story. So, the problem is that if you have some specific (not empty) route configured in some module and you just redirect to it from root - it works, but shows that route in the address bar. The question is how to define root empty route in the 'feature' component routing (read not app.component/app.routing)

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If the loaded routes also have an empty path, then the URL will not change.

Comment: Let's try that. In the plunker mentioned in the original post your app start url is http://run.plnkr.co/sHfsoqprJcCOhhe0/heroes. No matter what you do there's no way to get to just http://run.plnkr.co/sHfsoqprJcCOhhe0

Comment: So yes, I do want to see the output of ...heroes by default, but I'd like my start url not having /heroes in it.

Comment: Thank you. That looks like what I need. Did you only change app.routing.ts?

Comment: I also removed `heroes` from the path in `heroes.routing.ts`.